# CSS text rotation

Tags: css, rotation, transparency

I am trying to to overlay some rotated text over my images but I am having some difficulty with it. Here is my code without all the jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/vCbcz/4/

**Issues:**

- The span does not align with the div after the rotation
- The background transparency isn't showing up in Internet Explorer even though the span is positioned and I have added `filter: alpha(opacity = 30);` to my css.

EDIT: I would like the spans to look like http://jsfiddle.net/vCbcz/6/ except with rotated text. Please don't tell me to put the text in a seperate container.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "the span does not align with the div after the rotation'...  Can you include a link to an image of what it should look like?

Comment: Yeah, I think you'll need to put the text in another container.  You're rotating the container so it makes sense that the text in the container would rotate as well...

Comment: I want the text to be rotated. But the span gets moved over to the right after the rotation. I want the black background part to still be in the position as shown in the edit

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443750/webkit-transforms-how-to-roate-on-z-axis-but-not-around-center

Comment: The CSS rotation applies rotation around the center of an element _after_ it has been laid out. So you need to make sure the span is positioned with its center at the center of rotation prior to being rotated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `left:-25px;` on the spans fixes it for me in Firefox. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vCbcz/8/).

**Edit**
With regards to IE, the reason your alpha filter isn't being applied is because your second `filter:` is overwriting your first. If you want them to both be applied, you put them in the same `filter:` separated by a space like so:
`filter: alpha(opacity = 30) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);`

I noticed that in IE the `left:-25px;` makes it worse so perhaps you'll have to do some conditional comments or CSS hacks to get around it. (Icky!)

Just a warning, this doesn't work in Opera at all.

**Edit 2**
[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/vCbcz/11/) my changes with fixing IE's bugs and supporting Opera and possibly other browsers if they support the CSS3 `transform` property.

Comment: Thanks =) Any insight about the opacity problem?

Comment: @Luke Landwalker: I was just editing my answer for that. See above.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked great. Yea I was aware of the Opera issue but the browser isn't used by many people.

Comment: @Luke Landwalker: [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/vCbcz/11/) my changes with fixing IE's bugs and supporting opera.

Comment: @Luke Landwalker: I added a conditional comment (only visible to IE) into the HTML. It just overrides the other CSS since it's defined later.

Comment: Don't forget to add `bottom:25px;` to correct the height from 125px to 150px!